# Chrome popup: "It looks like you've moved... "

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

Not sure what happened over the weekend, but since this morning everytime I use google I get a popup from Chrome saying "It looks like you've moved. Would you like to use http://www.google.com/ ?"  (as opposed to my usual google.nl).

What does this mean, and how do I disable the popup? Clicking No or the close button didn't solve it, and I don't want to click Yes because I like my Google localized.

Comment: Crap, I accidently clicked yes and now all my searches are at .com...

Comment: Does [this](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95426) help ? @Litso

Comment: Nope. Set it to Google.nl, still searches at .com

Comment: Same problem. Even after selecting "No," the prompt returns every time I Google. Really irritating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `suggestion service` causes this you can disable it `under the hood` or try the following:

Clear your cookies, history and everything.
Try to add the languages you prefer and move them up in options->under the hood-> change fonts settings->languages.

[image: chrome language options]

Also locating a file called `Local State` and changing `last_known_google_url` and `last_prompted_google_url` to your preferred google address might help.

Answer (score 1):

Do other geolocation sites also think you're in the USA?  Maybe your ISP assigned you a misleading IP address. Try navigating to maps.google.com.

Also, try another browser.  (I notice you only mentioned Chrome.) If it's browser-specific, clear your cookies.